# Can't make A grid of divs scrollable

Tags: html, css, scroll, css-grid

I have a bunch of divs displaying in `grid` and the number of them changing dynamically, I want to make them `scrollable`, but when I'm adding to the container `overflow-y: scroll` I can't scroll down.
I think it's something with the height of the container but i don't know how to make it dynamically pick the height of all the divs.

currently that's what I have:

```
.container{
    overflow-y: scroll;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4,minmax(22vw, 1fr));
    gap: 20px;
}

.card{
    width: 20vw;
    height: 25vh;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: var(--secondary-color);
}
```

and this is the HTML:

```
<div className={style.container}>
 <div className={style.card}>
                <div className={style.pic} style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${pic})` }} />
                <div className={style.jam_details}>
                    <div className={style.jam_name}>
                        <span>Artist Name</span>
                        <span>, </span>
                        <span>Song Name</span>
                    </div>
                    <div className={style.jam_respect}>
                        <span>Likes</span>
                        <span>Songs</span>
                        <span>Playbacks</span>
                        <span>Released</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I expect the grid to be scrollable

Comment: You can define fix hight for the container.

Answer (score 1):

Three conditions must exist for any element to be scrollable:

1. It must have a definite height, either by assigning a `height` value other than `auto`, or by assigning an `aspect-ratio`.
2. It must have an appropriate `overflow` style (use `auto` to start with).
3. Its contents must actually overflow; it must contain sufficient content to require scrolling.

```css
.container {
    overflow: auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4,1fr);
    padding: 1em;
    gap: 1em;
    height: 60vh;
    border: 5px solid blue;
}

.card {
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: red;
    aspect-ratio: 1/1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
</div>
```